# Infinite Loop Error in TASM Assembler Code

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm currently writing a program which inputs a string, stores it in memory and then outputs back to screen. But I'm having trouble solving this task.

My source code:

```
IDEAL

MODEL small
STACK 100h

DATASEG

beggining db 100 dup(0)

CODESEG

Start:
   mov ax, @data
   mov ds, ax

   mov bx, offset beggining

myloop:

   mov ah, 06h
   mov dl, 0ffh
   int 21h

   mov [bx], al

   mov dl, [bx]
   mov ah, 02h
   int 21h

   inc bx

   cmp al, 13
   je quit   

   jmp myloop


quit:

   mov  ax, 4c00h
   int  21h


end Start
```

When I run the program with the source code shown above it doesn't work. It goes into an infinite loop.

Why doesn't my program print the characters that I've typed earlier??

BTW I'm writing in TASM.

Comment: Deceptively bad title for a reasonably made question... :)

Comment: Please give the URL or other resource from which you tried to copy this program.

Answer (score 0):

While Im not able to compile and test your code where I am at the moment, I believe int 21h/06h does not wait for a key to be pressed, it simply returns 0 for no-key (or extended key).  If this is the case your program would very VERY quickly trash memory.  I think you need 21h/07h to wait for a key if none is present in the keyboard buffer.

Comment: I can't remember it either, but [Ralf Brorws interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2559.htm) says `dl=0ffh` has special behavior. Not that we should be debugging this kind of problem in 2011, but there you go :)

Comment: Ok I tried using the 07h and this time the infinite loop didn't occur and it even shows my input. But why doesn't my program print the characters that I've typed?

Comment: try using ah as 06 for the character out.  I cant remember if you need to set the stdio output to use 02

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `INT 21H` function `01`, which reads a character from STDIN and echos it. So instead of

```
mov ah, 06h
mov dl, 0ffh
int 21h
```

You want:

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
```

Function `01h` is "cooked" console input. It inputs the character and echos. It also checks control-C and control-break, and will terminate your program if you press one of those keys. It might also interpret extended characters like Page Up, etc. I don't recall.

Function `07h` is "raw" console input. It doesn't check control-C or do any other preprocessing. It gives you exactly what was input.

Your question says that you're supposed to output the string after the user presses Enter, but I don't see any code that outputs the string that you've stored at `beggining`.

(by the way, the word is normally spelled "beginning")